# Create Azure Purview collection using API and Powershell

Tags: api, azure-powershell, azure-purview

This is the first time I am working with API.

I am trying to create a purview subcollection using API and powershell.

$tenantID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/token"

$params = @{ client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; grant_type = "client_credentials"; resource = ‘https://purview.azure.net’ }

$bearertoken = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Body $params -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json

$accesstoken = ConvertTo-SecureString $bearertoken.access_token -AsPlainText -Force

$purviewendpoint = "https://testpurview.purview.azure.com/account"

$url = "$purviewendpoint/collections/**newcollection1**?api-version=2019-11-01-preview"

```
$childcollection = @"
  {
    "parentCollection": {
      "referenceName": "**testpurview**"
    }
  }
"@
```

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url -Body $childcollection -Token $accesstoken

Steps I tried:

Created a bearer token.
Created a variable for access_token from bearer token.

newcollection1: new subcollection which I want to create.

testpurview : This is the root collection of my Purview account.

Can someone help me if this is the correct way to create collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the below approach.

```
$tenantId = "<tenant-id>"
$clientId = "<client-id>"
$clientSecret = "<client-secret>"
$accountName = "<purview-account-name>"
$parentCollectionId = "<parent-collection-id>"
$subcollectionName = "<subcollection-name>"

$context = Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $tenantId -ServicePrincipal -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId, (ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force)))

$token = $context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | Where-Object { $_.Resource -eq "https://purview.azure.net" } | Select-Object -First 1

$body = @{
    name = $subcollectionName
}

# Send the request to create the subcollection
$uri = "https://$accountName.purview.azure.com/collections/$parentCollectionId/subcollections?api-version=2021-07-01-preview"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)" } -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json)
```